# How do i save uploaded images in folder as well as database using JavaScript/Html.?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I need to save an uploaded image file which is uploaded from my local machine.

The code should save the image when clicking submit button with "file saved successfully" message and it should be saved to my local database.

Am using Angular js. But the code/idea can be from anything. JavaScript and html could be better for this perhaps?

Comment: You can't connect to a database with pure JavaScript, or HTML. To connect to a database you will require some server side scripting language to support it, such a PHP.

Comment: @doveyg thanks for your kind replay sir..!! could you pls explain me  how to save image using PHP,.? first of all i  need to understand uploading & saving process in php..!!!

Answer (score 1):

Saving something to a database is done server-sided. if you would like to use Javascript on the server instead of learning a new language then I would suggest learning [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/)

Comment: sir actually my project is based on Angular and Nodejs. i  asked my question as how to do it in javascript, is just for make myself to understand clearly..!!! it could be better if you share how to achieve this with angular and Nodejs..!!                        Thanks in advance Sir..

Comment: Are you running on express?

Comment: No sir, but in basic mode only..!!

Answer (score 0):

In order to save a file using server-side scripting, such a PHP. you can either use an AJAX request or not, however the mechanism is;

```
<form method="post" action="demo_form.php">
  <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Once the form has been submitted, either using AJAX or a regular HTTP request. You must then read the file back you can do this by using the `$_FILE` array and then save it as something like a binary object in your database or to the file system with a path to the file.

Following these instructions you should be able to recall the file whenever required.

Comment: Sir,  this is what i did actually, but with some slight changes in my code. like  as follows:                                                                                  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload"> 
 <input type="file" name = "file" accept="image/"> <input type="submit" value="submit">


 </form>

Comment: The action attribute must correspond to a script the user can access/run, yours is just a folder. The script will be used to process the request, and the script (in PHP, o a similar language) must be written by you unless you get lucky and find one that performs the exact task in the exact way you are looking for.

Comment: yeah i understand  @doveyg sir,  Well, Thanks for sharing your great knowledge with me sir..!!